# Data Fusion: GCS create creating folders not object

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion, cdap

I am trying to create an GCS object (File) with GCS create plugin of Data Fusion.
[image]

but it is creating a folder instead.

[image]

How I can have a file created instead of a folder ??

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the description of the plugin leads to a misunderstanding. Cloud Storage doesn't work like a conventional filesystem, so you cannot "strictly" create empty files. [The gsutil command](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/quickstart-gsutil) doesn't have an equivalent to a `touch` command (on Linux) and all "basic" operation in this product is limited to the `cp` command (upload and download files).

Therefore, since there is no file when you specify the storage url, it's expected that a folder will be created instead of a file.

Based on this, I would like to suggest you two workarounds:

1. If you are using this plugin to create a file as a ‘flag’, you can continue using the plugin since the created folder also serves as a flag (to trigger a Cloud Function, for example)
2. If you need to create a file, you can create files with the GCS plugin located in ‘Sink’ plugins group to write records to one or more files in a directory on Google Cloud Storage. Files can be written in various formats such as csv, avro, parquet, and json.